# How to make your code stop executing next line until a function finishes its work in flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

I have a cloud storage where i store the data by uploading it from my app. And I also have a cloud firestore database where i store the file names and urls of those uploaded files. The problem which I am facing is my code is trying to collect the url before the datas/files are uploaded, therefore it crashes. So I want my code to stop there finish the task and go to next lines. I even used async/await in my code but still it doesn't help.

Here is my code:-

```
 Future savingfile(List<int> asset, String name) async {
    StorageReference reference = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child(name);
    StorageUploadTask uploadTask = reference.putData(asset);
    String url = await (await uploadTask.onComplete).ref.getDownloadURL();
    //print(url);
    //documentFileUpload(url);
    return url;
 }
 getfilelink(String s) async {
    StorageReference ref = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child('$s');
    String url = (await ref.getDownloadURL()).toString();

    return url;
  }
 saveeverything(List filechosen) async {
    for (int i = 0; i < filechosen.length; i++) {
      await savingfile(filechosen[i].readAsBytesSync(), filenames[i]);
    }
  }

void updatedata() async {
    ..... //some more codes are here.

    await saveeverything(filechosen); //i want my code to wait and finish the task over here and go to next line.

    String fileurl = "", filedetails = "";
      if (filenames.length == 0) {
          filedetails = "none";
          fileurl = "none";
        } else {
          for (int i = 0; i < filenames.length; i++) {
            filedetails += filenames[i].toString() + " ";
          }
          for (int i = 0; i < filenames.length; i++) {
            String t =  getfilelink(filenames[i]) + " ";
            fileurl += t;
          }
        }
    
    await notices.add({
      "event": notice,
      "date": date,
      "description": detail,
      "index": ds.docs.length + 1,
      "files": filedetails,
      "url": fileurl
    });
}
```

That's my code, I hope you understand it.

Here's the error which I am getting

```
E/flutter ( 4499): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(166)] Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: Class 'Future<dynamic>' has no instance method '+'.
E/flutter ( 4499): Receiver: Instance of 'Future<dynamic>'
E/flutter ( 4499): Tried calling: +(" ")
```

Thank you!

Comment: i didn't get your point

Comment: I dont have any analysis_options.yaml file.. I cant find it

Comment: Your error is from doing: `getfilelink(filenames[i]) + " "`.  `getfilelink` is `async`, so it returns a `Future` that must be `await`ed before you can use `+` on it. (Also, you should declare return types for your functions.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your updatedata function must be of type Future<void> (not sure if this works or if to has to be Future<bool> to return some result.

In your stateful/less class you finally wait for the future to come, so something like

```dart
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder( 
            future: _yourFuture,
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
```

Comment: My code isn't going to be run in the beginning its going to be ran after a button was tapped so I dont any widget and also i have nothing to built too, is it possible to do without the future builder?

Comment: you can put the FutureBuilder right in front of the outputting widget like builder: (context, snapshot) { Text(myFutureText);} Until the load has completed, you would want to display some spinning wheel at this very spot.

Comment: if this helped, accepting or upvoting the answer would be nice :-)